# Error ORA-00904 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: oracle

El problema que tengo es que no se asigna correctamente el valor a la variable que estoy declarando:

```
Declare
perro VARCHAR(20) := 'bag';
Begin
execute immediate ' update CLIENTE set PAIS = ' || perro  ;

END;
/
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por las dudas... ¿Revisaste la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)? ¿Te fijaste en los [ejemplos](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm)?

Comment: por favor, no pongais pantallazos.... al final no se pueden copiar los ejemplos

Answer (score 4):

Como decía en el comentario a la pregunta, *hay que leer la documentación*.
En realidad el error no está en la declaración de la variable, sino en la sintaxis que estás utilizando para el `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Hice una prueba rápida en base a la sintaxis vista en [estos ejemplos](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm) y no hubo problemas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (PAIS VARCHAR(80));
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE; /* Tabla vacía */
```

```sql
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES ('prueba');
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE; /* 1 resultado: PAIS = prueba */
```

```sql
DECLARE
    sql_s VARCHAR(200);
    perro VARCHAR(20) := 'bag';
BEGIN
    sql_s := 'UPDATE CLIENTE SET PAIS = :1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_s USING perro;
END;
/


/* una fila afectada */
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE; /* 1 resultado: PAIS = bag */
```

> Nótese el empleo de `USING` y el paso del parámetro a la consulta.